# replace default submit button with image not working

Tags: html, css, forms, submit

I am trying to replace my submit button with an image using background-image in CSS, this however is giving it a background image but the default submit button is still in the foreground with the text over it. I have also tried adding an image in my HTML but it doesn't show image, I'm guessing because the type is still submit. Is there a way to do this without changing it to type=image? surely there is as I have seen it work on other examples but its just not working for some reason on mine :/

Here is my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/e94yh/

HTML

```
 <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" src="../assets/images/submit.png"/>
</form>
```

CSS

```
 input[type=submit]{
cursor: pointer;
 }

 #submit {
width:100px;
height:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `background:url('');` and `color:transparent;`

**CSS**

```
input[type=submit]{
background:url('../assets/images/submit.png');
cursor: pointer;
```

color:transparent;
     }

instead of `src=""`

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/KhNtH/)

Comment: this is just giving the submit button a background image I can still see the submit text on top of the image.

Comment: @ev9604 just use color:transparent;

Comment: @ev9604: i think my answer has helped you to get the background image for the submit button

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/e94yh/3/)**</kbd>

I guess you need to use `type="image"` in order to achieve what you want.

An input button with an image :

```
<input type="image" src="../assets/images/submit.png" value="submit" id="submit">
```

Using CSS in order to style button

```
<input type="submit" class="myButton" value="submit" id="submit">

.myButton {
    background:url(../assets/images/submit.png) no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 100px;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if I change the value to "" it removes the submit text.

Comment: check my fiddle and answer..!! use color transparent..!!